# Cant import an already installed module

Tags: python-3.x, module, pytube

I installed a library called **pytube** using the command line `python -m pip install pytube` and I get that the module is successfully installed , bit when I try to import it , i get an error that the module doesnt exist , I use visual studio code if this is relevant.

Help please

Comment: Did you mean `pip` instead of `pop`?

Comment: What if you use `python3`, not `python`, to install the library?